# How to find an equation a mirroring point on 2D space mark by a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

At 2D space we three points (p1, p2, p3) which coordinates has been known as (x,y). p1 and p2 defines the mirror line.

The distances of p4 and p3 to the p1-p2 line is the same and the line between p3 to p4 is perpendicular to the p1, p2 line.

What I have been trying to find is equations consist of p1, p2, p3 which gives p4 coordinates.

I spend two days and failed.

[image: Fig. 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find $H$ which is the intersection of $(p_1 p_2)$ and $(p_3 p_4)$, it is the orthogonal projection of $p_3$ on $(p_1 p_2)$ so

$$ H = p_1 + \frac{(\overrightarrow{p_1p_3}\cdot\overrightarrow{p_1p_2})}{\Vert \overrightarrow{p_1 p_2}\Vert^2}\,\overrightarrow{p_1 p_2}$$

Then, $p_4 = H + \overrightarrow{p_3H}$, that you should be enough for you to find coordinates of $p_4$

$$x_4 = 2\left(x_1 + \frac{(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)+(y_3-y_1)(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\,(x_2-x_1)\right)-x_3$$
$$y_4 = 2\left(y_1 + \frac{(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)+(y_3-y_1)(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\,(y_2-y_1)\right)-y_3$$

Comment: I will be back.

Comment: I've tested it on GeoGebra just to backcheck, the formula is correct.

Comment: I found solution using trigonometry and your equation giving to the same result. I confess that I could not understand this vectorial explanation, I think I am better at trigonometry. But considering the time I spend it is doubtful as well. I did not think about since your answer though. But after weeks I sit and found solution in 15 minutes.

Comment: I would like to add my answer here but it will take some drawings and work, maybe later.